# How to open share sheet when the user clicks on the primary button of firebase in app messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I want to use firebase in app messaging to implement app announcements. In the firebase console, you can attach a weblink or a deeplink that will be launched when the user clicks on the primary button.

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKmBW.png)

My goal is to make the button open the android share sheet with the app's URL to make the user share the app with their friends. How can I do that?

I tried to search for ways to create an intent that opens the share sheet but nothing worked.